# Did the 1st Marine Division use the M3 carbine on Okinawa?

Tags: world-war-two, war, technology, weapons, ww2-pacific-theater

I wanted to know if the 1st Marine Division used the M3 infrared sniper carbine on Okinawa during World War II.

Comment: Sniper rifles aren't distributed to "*units*", they are assigned to the "*designated snipers*" in many units. Given the ***very*** high casualties believed to have been inflicted by these weapons relative to their very small number (only about 150), they must have been widely distributed.

Comment: Ask the question you want answered - and edit it into the question as questions must stand independent of their comments.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Answer (score 10):

Was the M3 carbine used on Okinawa? Yes, as the T3 carbine with the T120 sniperscope. They would later be classified as the M3 carbine with the M1 sniperscope.

[image: T3 Carbine with M2 sniperscope]

[Note: pictured is a T3 carbine with an M2 sniperscope]

While it had a scope, it wasn't a sniper weapon. The infrared scope had an effective range of about 70 meters which matched well with the short range of the [M1 carbine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1_carbine) it was derived from. The M3 was primarily used to great effect to defend against Japanese nighttime infiltration.

Was the 1st Marine Division issued any T3/T120s? I don't know, but I doubt it. It was an Army project and only about 150 were on Okinawa. I doubt they gave any to the Marines.

## Sources

- Forgotten Weapons: [M3 Infrared Sniper Carbine at RIA](https://www.forgottenweapons.com/m3-infrared-sniper-carbine-at-ria/)
- Rock Island Auction Company: [Lot 1788: Inland T3 Carbine 30 M1 Carbine](https://www.rockislandauction.com/detail/56/1788/inland-t3-carbine-30-m1-carbine) with "Repair Instructions for Sniperscopes M1 and M2" August 1951
- [The U.S. Carbine Caliber .30 Model M1E7 & Model T3](http://www.uscarbinecal30.com/modelT3.html)

Comment: I have a reference book on order to see if it has any further information.

Comment: Sorry, it turned out to have no further information.